# CSS to always center text in a page

Tags: css, text, centering

I am trying to add text to center of the page. Even if a user try to resize the page, text in the page should be aligned to center. I am close to the solution but missing some position in the code. Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/aKYyZ/). Any help would be highly appreciated.

html code

```
<div class="errorMessageContainer">

    <div class="errorMessageIcon">
        :(
    </div>
    <div class="errorMessageHeaderContainer">
        <div class="errorMessageHeader">
            I am trying to center me in a page.
        </div>
        <div class="errorMessageText">
            <span class="errorMessageSubHeader">I want to float.</span>Even if page is restored or forced minimized. <span class="errorContact"><a href="#">Please </a></span> help me on this.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
  body {
        background-color: #666666;
    }

    .errorMessageContainer {
        width: 620px;
        margin: 200px 0 0 300px;

    }

    .errorMessageIcon {
        font-family: Segoe UI Semibold;
        font-size: 72px;
        color: #29abe0;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .errorMessageHeaderContainer {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 500px;
        padding: 20px 0 0 30px;
    }

    .errorMessageHeader {
        font-family: Segoe UI Light;
        font-size: 28px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .errorMessageSubHeader {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .errorMessageText {
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 450px;
    }

    .errorContact a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will put your message container in center of the page :

```
.errorMessageContainer {
    width: 620px;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -310px;       
    margin-top: -50px;       
}
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKYyZ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.errorMessageContainer {
    width: 620px;
    margin: 200px auto 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin: 200px auto 0 auto;` for the `.errorMessageContainer` see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DSATE/

Answer (score 1):

```
.errorMessageContainer{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to set up your `display` and `margins` correctly. Do not set values for this otherwise it will fail if the div changes in size. heres an example I made up using a `div` wrapper and the value `display:table-cell`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/DSATE/1/